# Change Woothemes admin url

Tags: plugins

I would like to change the next url: `wp-admin/admin.php?page=woothemes`

I would like that "**woothemes**" to be anything else. Is that possible without breaking the site?

Comment: Seriously, why?

Comment: Yes, seriously ;) This is a question from a client.

Comment: But why!? Please don't tell me they're trying to disguise the fact it's Woothemes & ship as their own product...

Comment: They want to hide it from their competitors. This was their reason. They don't want their competitors to know what kind of plugins and themes they are using. Site has login section for users. Whatever, they asked me, I tried to get help here and the answer below is enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While WP API probably *would* allow to move it quite cleanly (there are some plugins that shuffle pages around for different purposes) it is very hard to say if it will just work without complete audit of relevant code for how it uses the page, how it generates link to it and if it will break when it is done.

It doesn't help that admin menu is considered one of the most unpleasant corners of WP code base to work with.